# "Technique" tag

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

I think the [technique](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) tag currently is also kind of meta tag that means different things for different people. Should we replace it with something less vague?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that it should be removed, and replaced with something more specific on the questions where it was intended to have a meaning.

The word itself doesn't have any specific meaning, and could be replaced with "how-to" or "method". As you say, it has different meanings for different people, and as such it is pretty useless as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

The word does have a specific meaning, according to:

- **Dictionary.com:**

  - *technical skill; ability to apply procedures or methods so as to effect a desired* result.
- **Meriam-Webster.com:**

  - *a method of accomplishing a desired aim*

To put it simply: *A technical method or procedure used to accomplish a result.*

I think there are some questions that could make use of the `[technique]` tag, so I would vote against getting rid of it completely. Using that tag in combination with actual techniques, such as the `[low-key]`, `[high-key]` example mentioned by Karel is an ideal situation where the term has value. If I want to find all techniques, I can simply click that tag, rather than having to individually look through each technique itself.

I would vote against using `[shot-discipline]`, as I don't really think most of our users are really going to make the connection between that and `[technique]`. In other cases, the question is asking about something involving post-processing of either film or digital images...in which case shot-discipline is not even relevant. In some cases, we should use the tag that relates to the thing people think of, and given the volume of threads that already use the technique tag, I would be wary of changing it. Lets not add convolution when we don't need to.

It may be valuable to have `[post-processing-technique]` and `[camera-technique]`, if we want to be able to find techniques of those two classes independently.

On the flip side, there are questions that make use of the technique tag that probably should not be:

- [What are your easiest beginner tips?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips)

  - The tags `[beginner]` and `[tips]` are probably fine, `[technique]` doesn't seem to fit.
- [How and why do you use an image histogram?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-and-why-do-you-use-an-image-histogram)

  - The other tags are ok, however there really isn't any technique to viewing a histogram.
- [Are colour filters worth using with digital cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-colour-filters-worth-using-with-digital-cameras)

  - The question really isn't asking about techniques involving color filters, rather it is asking if they are useful. The `[technique]` tag should probably be removed.

Comment: There are different problems here.
1) [technique] is very general term and tagging with it doesn't really add anything to the system, just like "subjective" and "beginner". It also gets confused with "technical".
2) I suggested to tag shooting techniques separately, whatever the tag name will be ([shooting-technique] is just fine).
3) Having separate tags for printing and post-processing techniques is also fine by me (I actually suggested that).
PS: you're assigning my quote to matt.

Comment: I agree, we should have more fine-grained technique tags. I think `[shooting-technique]`, `[processing-technique]`, `[printing-technique]` are all useful. We can easily search for all techniques by using *-technique in the tags page.

Answer (score 0):

When I talk about technique I mean **shot discipline/shooting technique**, not [post-processing technique](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-stop-my-hdr-shots-looking-so-fake) (which has a tag by itself), nor technical details about [how the camera works](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/803/how-do-spherical-lens-produce-rectangular-shots).

My suggestion is to rename [technique] to [shooting-technique] and remove this tag from not shooting related questions.

More examples:

- [shooting-technique] [low-key] makes sense (personal opinion of course)
- [printing] [technique] is not very good, because everything is already said with [printing]; when we talk about printing techniques, then for example [printing] and [dye-transfer] will do
- we can exclude [technique] from the set [post-processing], [sharpen], [technique] without losing anything important

Comment: I agree, except for the shot-discipline part. I would prefer something that is closer to the original, like shooting-technique.

Comment: To me, [low-key] is as descriptive as [shot-discipline][low-key] is, in pretty much the same ways as [printing] implies [printing][technique].  I think [shot-discipline] also fails the usability test; it's not common enough to get used in practice.

Comment: @chills42, matt - sure, I'm open to different naming suggestions as I'm not a native speaker anyway (so my version is probably not the best from usability perspective).

Comment: @matt - [low-key] vs [shot-discipline][low-key], when you add [shot-discipline][high-key], they now have a common denominator, which is a good thing from my perspective.

Comment: I updated my answer and replaced [shot-discipline] with [shooting-technique] as it's more usable. Anybody who previously started to type "technique", will now get an auto-complete to shooting-technique and if their question doesn't fit, they're probably not going to use it. Or use printing-technique, once that appears and fits better to their question.

Comment: @Karel - it still strikes me as the same kind of meta tag that it's supposed to be fixing. I see your point about high-key and low-key, but two responses: a better common root would be 'lighting', and it creates false connections with other techniques that are possibly only vaguely related, e.g., zone-focus.

Comment: Maybe you're right, maybe my example was bad. It _is_ actually hard to define what goes under shooting-technique (HDR, panorama, key, etc, they all require some kind of technique during shooting). I think it leads to a larger problem whether the tag system should be a taxonomy or just bunch of keywords which pretty much depend on asker's choice. Or maybe this "problem" is caused by the low activity on the main site:) What's your suggestion?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean: if 'technique' is problematically broad, then so is 'shooting-technique'.  My suggestion is to eliminate it as a category.  Try this for a thought experiment: if 'printing-technique' is a suggestion, how is that different to 'printing'. I don't mean in the sense of 'can you find one counter-example', but in an impression of the overall difference between those two: a definition of what they signify and how they differ.

Comment: Well, looks like this discussion doesn't lead us anywhere. I'll leave it as is.